# Cleaning up CSV Data Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV that holds information on file paths. The full file path can be created if I merge the cells together and add "/" between them. Sometimes these cells can be empty or have multiple directories in them. Eg. Desktop/FolderA/FolderB

So for that I’ve got the script:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'test.csv'  | 
Select-Object @{Name='Path';Expression={$_.Folder1, "/" ,$_.Folder2, "/",$_.Folder3, "/",$_.Folder4, "/",$_.Folder5, "/", $_.Folder6, -join ','}}    | 
Export-Csv 'OutputTestFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

This produces the output test file that looks a bit like:

> HR Central /  /  / HR Central / Documents /  ,
>
> HR Central / Employee Services /  / Employee Services - Internal /
>   Employee Services / Procedures/a/b/c ,
>
> HR / HR Business Partners /  / Talent & Acquisition - Internal / HR
>   Business Partners /  ,

Which doesn't make for clean file paths because of the double slashes. Spaces are also an issue. I don’t even need to export it back to a CSV. I need to just be able to grab a list/array of file paths so I can create the file structure within an environment.

Ideally I'd like the file paths to look like this:

> HR/HR Business Partners/Talent & Acquisition - Internal/HR Business
>   Partners/,
>
> HR Central/HR Central/Documents/,

Comment: take a look at the `Join-Path` cmdlet. [*grin*] _it knows about path delimiters_ and will handle that particular glitch for you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
foreach ( $csvLine in $(Import-Csv -Path 'test.csv')) {
    $rawPath = $csvLine | Select-Object @{
        Name='Path';
        Expression = { @( $_.Folder1, 
                          $_.Folder2, 
                          $_.Folder3, 
                          $_.Folder4, 
                          $_.Folder5, 
                          $_.Folder6) -join '/'
                    }
        }
    # remove multiple solidi
    $rawPath.Path.Split(
         '/', 
         [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -join '/'
}
```

Comment: I picked this answer because I was also wondering how to join different folder names and it's really expanded so I can see what's going on. Thanks peeps!

Answer (score 1):

One of many options:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'test.csv' |
    Select-Object @{
        Name = 'Path'
        Expression = {
            $row = $_
            $folders = @()
            1..6 | ForEach-Object {
                $folder = $row."Folder$_"
                if ($folder -and -not ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($folder.Trim())))
                {
                    $folders += $folder.Trim()
                }
            }
            return $folders -join "/"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be pretty short if you use the `PSObject`. If you just want an array of paths I'd do it in a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
Import-Csv test-csv | Select Folder[1-6] | ForEach-Object {
    $_.psobject.Properties.where({$_.Name -match '^Folder[1-6]$' -and !([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Value))}).Value -join '/' -replace '(?<=/) | (?=/)'}
}
```